# ¿Cuál es la función real del operador "<<" en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

En diferentes páginas me han dado diferentes ejemplos y aún no entiendo realmente el funcionamiento del operador `<<`

```js
var a = 4 << 3;
var b = 4 << 5;

console.log("a = "+a + " y b = " +b);
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo, si [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99392/16841) de @Xique ha solucionado tus dudas, sugiero que la marques como aceptada, de lo contrario, si aún quedan dudas sería bueno que las sepamos para poder seguir ayudándote ;)

Comment: @Xique ha explicado claramente el significado del operador. Como aportación adicional, comentar que rara vez se ve este operador cuando se construye un web o una app, la "función real"  habitual, es para desarrollar funciones mas complejas, como por ejemplo, [un generador de números aleatorios](https://github.com/AndreasMadsen/xorshift/blob/master/xorshift.js).

Answer (score 29):

Justo como lo dice [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/bitwise-left-shift-operator-decrement-javascript), desplaza el número de posiciones (indicado con el número de la derecha) del binario del numero de la izquierda, por ejemplo:

El número 4 en binario es 100 con el operador `<<` hacemos que el binario se desplace agregando ceros al binario del número, entonces:

**(Se agregan 3 ceros a la derecha del binario de 4 que es 100 )**

`4 << 3 == 100000` que  si lo convertimos  por el valor 1 en la posición 5 del binario es igual a:

> 32

**(Se agregan 5 ceros a la derecha del binario de 4 que es 100 )**

`4 << 5 == 10000000` que si lo convertimos por el valor 1 en la posición 8 del binario es igual a:

> 128

Un ejemplo mas sencillo el 1 en binario seria `01`, con el operado quedaría  de la siguiente forma:

```
1 << 1 == 2 == 10
1 << 2 == 4 == 100
1 << 3 == 8 == 1000
```

***...***

Ejemplos:

```js
var a = 4 << 3;
var b = 4 << 5;
var c = 1 << 1;
var d = 1 << 2;
var e = 1 << 3;
console.log("a = "+a)
console.log("b = "+b)
console.log("c = "+c)
console.log("d = "+d)
console.log("e = "+e)
```

Comment: Gran respuesta, creo que sería aún mejor si comentaras que esta operación puede provocar que se trunque el resultado (1 << 32 == 1)

Comment: cambiaría la palabra "recorre" por "desplaza" sino como que cambia el significado y se pierde

Answer (score 3):

Este operador << se llama ShiftLeft y >> es ShiftRight lo que hace es que en notacion binaria ShiftLeft desplaza el numero binario de la izquierda tantos ceros hacia la izquierda como diga el numero de la derecha e inversamente lo hace ShiftRight:

4 << 2 es 100 << 2 lo cual queda en binario 10000 que es 16.

Esto servia antes ya que la ALU(Unidad Aritmeticologica) solo podia sumar,restar, hacer AND Logico y dejar el valor Del buffer principal igual que como habia ingresado y cuando se necesitaba usar multiplicacion y division como te daras cuenta, con solo esas operaciones, eran muchas las iteraciones necesarias y por lo tanto mucho uso de CPU, pero esto es tema de arquitecturas de computadoras que es solo sirve para explicarte que estos dos simbolos previamente mencionados sirven para:

multiplicar un numero N por 2^M en el caso de shiftleft:

N << M -> 4<<2 -> (4*(2^2)) = 16.

O dividir N por M^2 en el caso de shiftRight

N>>M  -> 8>>3 == 8/(2^3) = 1.

1000 >> 3 == 1.

Answer (score 1):

Son operadores a nivel de bits
Observa el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: Operador de bits en accion ejemplo desplazamiento a la izquierda]

¿Te preguntaras, para que sirve esto?
Una de sus principales utilidades era para optimizar el trafico de datos en la red con el metodo de Bitwise mediante el cual puedes lograr a tener o emular tipos de datos de hasta un bit.

Existen varios operadores de bit:

[Operadores de Bits Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp)

Comment: Muy clara y muy gráfica la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Los valores son almacenados en memoria en base binaria, lo que significa que cada bit tiene un peso de 2^N, así:

```
| 2^N | ... | 2^0 |
```

Para 8 bits:

```
   N  |   7 |  6 |  5 |  4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
Peso  | 128 | 64 | 32 | 16 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
```

Así tendriamos como ejemplos:

- 1 es representado en binario como `0000 0001` = (2^0)
- 4 es representado en binario como `0000 0100` = (2^2)
- 42 es representado en binario como `0010 1010` = (2^5 + 2^3 + 2^1)

Ahora, el operador `<< N` desplaza los bits N posiciones hacia la izquierda, teniendo el mismo ejemplo del post:

- `4 << 3`, en version binario `0000 0100 << 3`, y se obtiene `0010 0000`, que es 32
- `4 << 5`, en version binario `0000 0100 << 3`, y se obtiene `1000 0000`, que es 128
- `13 << 3`, `0000 1101 << 3` = `0110 1000` = 104

Desde otro punto de vista, desplazar un numero **a la izquierda** N posiciones equivale a multiplicarlo por 2^N.

Answer (score 0):

`var a = b << c;` convierte `b` en un número entero de 32 bits (entre -2147483648 y 2147483647) y lo desplaza   binariamente hacia la izquierda `c` posiciones. Como binario es base 2 cada desplazamiento equivale a multiplicarlo por 2: `var a = 4 << 3;` es equivalente a `var a = parseInt(4) *2 *2 *2;` ó también  `var a = parseInt(4) * Math.pow(2,3);`

```js
var a = 4 << 3;
console.log("var a = 4 << 3;", a);

var a = parseInt(4) *2 *2 *2;
console.log("var a = parseInt(4) *2 *2 *2;", a);

var a = parseInt(4) * Math.pow(2,3);
console.log("var a = parseInt(4) * Math.pow(2,3);", a);

var a = 4.5 << 3;
console.log("var a = 4.5 << 3;", a);

var a = parseInt(4.5) *2 *2 *2;
console.log("var a = parseInt(4.5) *2 *2 *2;", a);

var a = parseInt(4.5) * Math.pow(2,3);
console.log("var a = parseInt(4.5) * Math.pow(2,3);", a);
```